# How to submit Multiple Options & multiple forms in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I have a html/php form like the following:

Form 1:

```
Apple
 options:
   -big
   -medium
   -small
Submit button
```

Form 2:

```
Orange
 options:
   -big
   -medium
   -small
Submit button
```

Table:

```
Items
 id
 user_id
 fruit_type
 size
```

Question:

Currently, user has to click on "Submit" on each of the fruit they want to resize. Is there any way to combine this into one form so user can click submit all size-options once they finished choosing them? I don't know how to write a Mysql query that can handle this because the fruit_type is different on both forms.

Secondly, how do you make the form "remember" user's current size setting and default to that selection.

Comment: Basically just do 2 insert statements or combine both data in one insert query. See this link: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/

Comment: To remember, simply query current setting from your db upon page load, then create session handlers and save the setting in current session variables. From there just peek in the session variables values to populate your interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html form could be like this :

```
Apple :
    <input type="radio" name="apple" value="big">
    <input type="radio" name="apple" value="medium">
    <input type="radio" name="apple" value="small">


    Orange :
    <input type="radio" name="orange" value="big">
    <input type="radio" name="orange" value="medium">
    <input type="radio" name="orange" value="small">
```

Then in your php where you are getting the values you will have $_POST['apple'] and $_POST['orange'] with the selected values for each one.

With the 2 values, simply write 2 INSERT queries.